# iPhone - MapKit point location of all users

Tags: iphone, maps, location, mapkit

I need to create an application that will use MapKit framework to point the current user position and the position of other users that installed the app on their device.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to push (to a web service or other cloud database) the current position of the device using location services, then have the app pull from another service.